# Multiple arguments passing for a parameter not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Create Proc ABC
Declare @Var1 VARCHAR (MAX)
Declare @Var2 Int
As BEGIN 

Update Table Set Column = @Var1 where Column1 in (@Var2)

End
EXEC  ABC @Var1 = 'ABCD', 'ABCDE' @Var2= 14
```

THis multiple arguments passing for Varibale `@Var1` is not working

Comment: SQL server 2016

Comment: You can't pass multiple values in 1 parameter unless its a table-type parameter.

Comment: "not working" is a pointless comment. While Ezlo has already provided the answer, you should always post the complete error message whenever you post about a problem that produces an error. In addition. your posted logic (even if it produced no error) makes no sense. A column holds a single scalar value. So which rows in your table would be assigned the value of 'ABCD' and which rows would be assigned 'ABCDE'?

Comment: My mistake the query is like

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
EXEC ABC @Var1 = 'ABCD, ABCDE' @Var2= 14
```

Comment: It will not work, tried already. If I pass only 1 value for @Var1 it is working but not for more than 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the parameter value like a list with comma-separated values.

```
Create Proc ABC
Declare @Var1 VARCHAR (MAX)
Declare @Var2 Int
As BEGIN 

Update Table Set Column = @Var1 where Column1 in (@Var2)

End
EXEC  ABC @Var1 = '''ABCD'', ''ABCDE''' @Var2= 14
```

like -

```
EXEC  ABC @Var1 = '''ABCD'', ''ABCDE''' @Var2= 14
```